# T-SQL - How to Select and Group Multiple Records (in multiple columns) for Each Employee?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

We have a table that looks like following:

```
DATAID Last_Name    First_Name   ADDRESS
1         Smith        John         5000 Street
2         Smith        John         6666 Street
3         Doe          Jim          1111 Street
4         Doe          Jim          2222 Street
```

As you can see, `DATAID` is a unique field. Same employee has multiple addresses listed in multiple columns. There are many other columns with unique data for each employee which I didn't include in the example table above. For e.g., phone number, email, etc.

How can I group multiple records for each employee by employee's first and last name? I tried to do a JOIN and didn't get desired results. I also couldn't figure out how to return desired results by running `DISTINCT on first_name and last_name` only and displaying relevant data for each employee from multiple columns.

Comment: Is First Name and Last Name unique? Is it completely impossible for their to be 2 John Smiths?

Comment: And if you do have multiple rows for a given (first_name, last_name) pair - which one do you want to show/keep?

Comment: Which address do you want to select for each `first_name`, `last_name`? Or do you want to group them in one value coma separated??

Comment: When you group by First and Last name, what is your expected output?  You cannot group on First_ and Last_Name and expect only two rows (in the given example).  What do you expect to happen with Address? DataId?

Comment: first_name and last_name combined are unique, but in the table there are multiple records for the same John Smith. I want to pull all unique address, phone ,email, etc. records for John Smith and display in a way that John Smith's name only displays once and under it all his relevant addresses, emails and phone numbers. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.First_Name,
  t1.Last_Name,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.Address
    FROM Tablename AS t2
    WHERE t1.First_Name = t2.First_name AND t1.Last_Name = t2.Last_Name
    FOR XML PATH(''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Address
FROM tablename AS t1
GROUP BY t1.First_Name,
         t1.Last_Name;
```

This will give you the results grouped by `First_name` and `Last_Name` with the address coma separated.

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd333/1)

This will give you:

```
| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |                  ADDRESS |
-----------------------------------------------------
|        Jim |       Doe | 1111 Street, 2222 Street |
|       John |     Smith | 5000 Street, 6666 Street |
```

Comment: I get error "Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1. Cannot find either column "t1" or the user-defined function or aggregate "t1.last_name", or the name is ambiguous."

Comment: @user2561860 - It should work fine, see [**this demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd333/1), please check your columns' names, or you can edit that demo and show that issue that  you have